# Add Sharepoint Add-in/App programatically with JS or differently

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-addin, rest, app, sharepoint-framework

Is it possible to add an app programatically automatically when new site is created? For example calling endpoint, automating click etc. SideLoading is not allowed in production

Edit: target Sharepoint 2016

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can use the [ALM Rest API](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/apis/alm-api-for-spfx-add-ins), Its available in [CSOM, Powershell](https://gautamdsheth.wordpress.com/2017/11/24/automating-add-in-app-installation-using-alm-apis-with-csom-and-powershell-in-sharepoint-online/) aswell as [Javascript](https://github.com/calin1611/sharepoint-alm-api-exaple/blob/master/src/app.js).

Comment: Ah that seems good, but it is only for Sharepoint online right? I did not mention we have SP 2016 On Premise

Answer (score 0):

In your SharePoint 2016 you have a central app catalog. Solutions deployed to this app catalog, can be installed in any site collection.

Take a look at [PnP PowerShell](https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-PowerShell) and [list of commands](https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-PowerShell/tree/master/Commands/Apps). Install the module:

```
Install-Module SharePointPnPPowerShell2016
```

Useful commands:

```
Add-PnPApp -Path ./helloworld.sppkg

Install-PnPApp -Identity 66b00f6e-tw81-4ab7-8zx-e09c6f9132dc

Publish-PnPApp

Update-PnPApp -Identity 66b00f6e-tw81-4ab7-8zx-e09c6f9132dc

Remove-PnPApp -Identity 66b00f6e-tw81-4ab7-8zx-e09c6f9132dc
```